# Stop blink (jQuery plugin) using stopInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I am using this jQuery plugin for text blink http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blink

But I don't know how to modify it to do a .stopblink()

Can someone help?

Tanks

Comment: My god. It took forever for <blink> to be deprecated in the first place! Why would someone want to bring it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach another method to the plugin that does a `clearInterval()` on the `setInterval()` that is used to toggle the `visibility` CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

With that improved version (source code inside [post "Here is an improved the"](http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin#comment-976)) you can stop blinking this way ...

```
$('.blink').unblink();
```

Blink for a while and stop ...

```
$('.blink').blink();
setTimeout("$('.blink').unblink();", 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some users are improving jquery-blink in the comments of the official page

http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin